# How to compile and run java code inside JEdit?

Tags: java, ide

Hey I'm trying out JEdit, is there any way to compile and run the java code inside jedit, like many other java IDEs?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to install a plugin. jCompile is probably the one you're looking for. You can install it from the Plugin Manager (from the Plugins menu)

There's also an Ant plugin if you're into building you're projects that way.

http://plugins.jedit.org/